# Asp.net 4.5 WebForms ModelBinding not allowing setting selectedvalue on dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, binding, model, selectedvalue, selectmethod

I'm using Asp.net 4.5 model binding.  I have a dropdownlist that has a select method which returns an IEnumerable list of Products.  Everything works as expected.  However, when I land on the page, I need to check a querystring and change the selectedvalue of the dropdownlist (which is bound using the SelectMethod.

Typically I would simply use...

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ddlProducts.SelectedValue = Request.QueryString["productid"];
        }
    }
```

That however, does not work when the dropdownlist is bound to the SelectMethod (new asp.net 4.5 modelbinding).  So how can I set the selectedvalue of the dropdownlist via a querystring when I land on the page?

ASPX (Normal Dropdownlist used but with a SelectMethod):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProducts" runat="server" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="ProductId" AppendDataBoundItems="True" SelectMethod="GetProducts"></asp:DropDownList>
```

CS

```
public static IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
{
    using (var db = new AppDb())
    {
        return db.Products.OrderBy(x => x.Description).ToList().AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, so your mileage may vary.
But I think All you have to do is change your definition of getProducts:
from

```
public static IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
```

to

```
public static IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts([QueryString("somequerystringvariablename")] string param)
```

and then use 'param' to filter your query